# Trouble finding local minimum using SciPy

Tags: optimization, scipy, minimize

I'm trying to find the local minima for the function **fun(alpha)** defined in the code below.  A graphical depiction of this objective function can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOd8v.png).  As the graph illustrates, there are 3 local minima for alpha between 0 and 1.  They are approximately around alpha = .08, alpha = .26, and alpha = .98.  My problem is that regardless of which Scipy optimization algorithm I use (L-BFGS-B, Nelder-Meade, or COBYLA) or my initial starting value, I am unable to find the local minimum around alpha = .26. The other local minima are always found instead.  To illustrate this problem, in the code below I select an initial alpha of .3 only to have the L-BFGS-B algorithm find the .08 minimum.  Given the smoothness of this function, I'm surprised SciPy is having such a difficult time finding the .26 minimum.  Am I missing something in the L-BFGS-B options that would help the algorithm along?  Guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as opt
import math
P=54
R=132
S=28
T=162
rho=2.0
sigma=-0.112
lam=.5
n=3
m=(n-1)/2

def nCr(n,r):
    f = math.factorial
    return f(n) / f(r) / f(n-r)


def g(alpha,lam):

    sum1=0.0
    for x in range(0,m+1):
        sum1+=nCr(n,x)*alpha**x*(1-alpha)**(n-x)

    sum2=0.0
    for x in range(m+1,n+1):
        sum2+=nCr(n,x)*alpha**x*(1-alpha)**(n-x)

    return 1/float(1+np.exp(lam*nCr(2*m,m)*alpha**m*(1-alpha)**m*(sum1*(P-(S+n/float(2*n-1)*sigma*(T-S)))+sum2*(T-n/float(2*n-1)*rho*(T-S)-R))))

def fun(alpha):      
    return np.square(g(alpha,lam)-alpha)

F=np.zeros((1,1001))
alphas=np.linspace(0,1,1001)
indexAlpha=0
for alpha in alphas:
    F[0,indexAlpha]=fun(alpha)
    indexAlpha+=1

print
plt.ylim([0,1])
[a] = plt.plot(alphas,np.transpose(F))
plt.ylabel('fun')
plt.xlabel('alpha')
plt.show()  
print

alpha0=.3
results=opt.minimize(fun, alpha0, method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=[(0,1)]) 
print "fun:",results.fun[0]
print "alpha:",results.x[0]
```

Comment: Just some comments: (1) What is the use-case here? Without regulization/penalties, the minimizers do not care which minimum is found. So why expect them to hit your desired one? You are using very powerful tools when all you want is Gradient-descent with a starting-point. ```I'm surprised SciPy is having such a difficult time finding the .26 minimum```: It's totally fine behaviour giving what those minimizers are doing. (2) You tried quite different optimizers, but why not *SLSQP* which directly works with your example while *COBYLA* does not even take bounds (given in your example).

Comment: I expect them to find the .26 minimum when I start with an initial alpha on the hill that is adjacent to it.  My understanding is that L-BFGS-B is a gradient based method that searches in the direction of the greatest downward change (which is what I believe you are referring to as gradient-descent?), so how the algorithm jumps hills to find a different local minimum is puzzling to me.  Edit: I just tried SLSQP with an initial alpha of .3 like you suggested and it successfully found the .26 minimum!  I'm glad it worked, but it'd be nice to know why the other optimizers weren't finding it.

Comment: It's much more complicated then that as it's not Gradient-descent. If you want to get a grasp on what's going on, check Nocedal, Wright "Numerical Optimization" (there are free pdfs with a bit of search, ~1000 pages of interesting stuff incl. BFGS, LBFGS, SLSQP). For L-BFGS-B it's especially hard to forecast it's behaviour because of the inner hessian-approximations. Saying that brings me to some broader difference which i should mention here: Gradient-descent is a first-order method; BFGS-type methods are second-order methods. That alone is enough to observe quite a different behaviour.